# How to register a renderer for a class in JSP/JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I was wondering if there is a way to register default renderer for a particular class in JSP/JSTL.

I am on my page displaying a tabular report where each table row arrives as generic `List<Object>`. Since I don't know the type of particular item in advance I am outputting the value with `<c:out ...>`. This does `toString()` as far as I know.

Now I want to change the format based on the class of the item e.g. change the format of decimal numbers. Of course I can't use `<fmt:formatXXX ...>` because I don't know the type in advance.

I believe this is possible in JSF. But is there a way how to achieve this in JSP?

My best shot sofar would be to convert the `List<Object>` to `List<String>` and applying the formatting  in my controller class but this is slightly less elegant than register a renederer IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP has no notion of "renderers", it's not a component based MVC framework. But you could create a [custom tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) for this.

Alternatively, you can do something like this with plain JSTL, it's possible to figure the class of an EL object by just checking `Object#getClass()`:

```html
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${item['class'].name == 'java.lang.Integer'}">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${item}" type="number" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${item['class'].name == 'java.math.BigDecimal'}">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${item}" type="currency" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${item['class'].name == 'java.util.Date'}">
        <fmt:formatDate value="${item}" type="date" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="${item}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```